# Finding the sum of values in cells that also contain other text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, worksheet-function, vba

I have an Excel sheet with a lot of values within a single cell as follows:

```
a=5  
b=10  
c=44  
d=33  
...
```

I would like to extract to total sum of the values after each `=` character.

How can we do that?

Comment: Bit more information needed. Are all of your strings of the precise form: "text1=#1, text2=#2, text3=#3,..." where the #n are integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this small *User Defined Function UDF*:

```
Public Function SumInCell(s As String) As Double
    Dim s2 As String, d As Variant
    s2 = s & ","
    ary = Split(s2, "=")

    SumInCell = 0
    For i = LBound(ary) + 1 To UBound(ary)
        s2 = ary(i)
        d = CDbl(Mid(s2, 1, InStr(1, s2, ",") - 1))
        SumInCell = SumInCell + d
    Next i
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=SumInCell(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a layout as shown in ColumnA, copy ColumnA to ColumnB, apply Text to Columns on ColumnB with `=` as delimiter and then in C5:

```
=SUM(C1:C4)
```

[image: SO29419251 example]

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to divide it into columns, I want to keep the single cell as it is because it is very huge and then I would need a very long formula to sum all the values, I need something to sum the values while they are still within that single cell.

Answer (score 1):

for a formula answer you will need to do it in 2 cells so you dont hit the nested limit of excel

if your value is in A1,

IN B1 put

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"=","'")),"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z","")," ","")&","
```

In C1 put

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(B1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"'","@",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"'",""))))))+1,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(B1,",","*",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))))))-(FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"'","@",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"'",""))))))+1))+0)
```

> this took awhile to work out:)